# OpenERP (Python) - _track with additional information

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, openerp-7

Is it possible to add additional information when field is tracked? For example let say there are two fields:

```
_track = {
  'field1': {},
  'field2': {},
}
```

I need to track those fields if anything is changed in those fields. And that is OK, but the problem is that those fields labels are the same for example like this:

```
_columns = {
  'field1': fields.integer('Number', track_visibility='onchange'), 
  'field2': fields.integer('Number', track_visibility='onchange')
```

}

I don't want to change their labels, because those labels should be the same as they represent same thing but in different time. But is it possible to add aditional information when tracking occurs, for example instead of just showing like this:

`Number: 1 - > 2`

It would show like this:

`Number: 1 -> 2 "before field" #when field1 is changed`

`Number: 2 -> 3 "after field" #when field2 is changed`

In other words, is it possible to give additional information so user that sees the what change happened, he would understand for which field it happened. Now it just shows that change happened to 'Number' field, but to which one it is not clear.